# How can I be redirected to another application through wso2 apim

Tags: security, wso2

I wish to know how to to access an application passing through wso2 apim. I do not want to go straight to the applications but instead I want to hit a certain wso2 url on my browser, lets say I hit https://localhost:9443/odoo and am taken to https://localhost:8069/web/login which is the url of odoo. I do not wish to hit the odoo url directly but wish to go through wso2 apim. Please how can I configure this in wso2? How can I do the url mappings or claims. Thank you

I tried to do some mappings and claims but didn't get the results